# Cannot link to self-built Tensorflow on Windows with Visual Studio when /WHOLEARCHIVE option is active

Tags: c#, c++, tensorflow, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I followed [this tutorial](https://joe-antognini.github.io/machine-learning/windows-tf-project) to build Tensorflow 1.5 from source on Windows 10 (with Visual Studio 2015, CUDA 9.0, cuDNN 7 using CMake). I was able to successfully compile Tensorflow, however I can't compile a separate, very simple C++ program that interfaces with Tensorflow. The program just tries to instantiate a session, so it looks like this:

```
#define COMPILER_MSVC
#define NOMINMAX
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
using namespace tensorflow;

void load_model() {

    auto session = NewSession(SessionOptions());
    if (session == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "could not open session" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "session successfully opened" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    load_model();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that without any additional linker flags, the program compiles, but then I get a runtime error saying

> Not found: No session factory registered for the given session
>   options: {target: "" config: } Registered factories are {}.

I've searched for this error and found this related [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3308), which says that you have to add the `/WHOLEARCHIVE` option in the linker settings. So I added the following statements:

```
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc.lib 
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc_framework.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc_ops.lib 
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_cpu.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_direct_session.lib 
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_framework.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_kernels.lib 
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_lib.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_ops.lib   
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_stream_executor.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:libjpeg.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:nsync.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:snappy.lib
```

However, using those options, the build failes with tons of linker errors, two of them shown here:

```
1>tf_core_kernels.lib(adjust_contrast_op.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl tensorflow::functor::AdjustContrastv2<struct Eigen::GpuDevice>::operator()(struct Eigen::GpuDevice const &,class Eigen::TensorMap<class Eigen::Tensor<float const ,4,1,__int64>,16,struct Eigen::MakePointer>,class Eigen::TensorMap<class Eigen::TensorFixedSize<float const ,struct Eigen::Sizes<>,1,__int64>,16,struct Eigen::MakePointer>,class Eigen::TensorMap<class Eigen::Tensor<float,4,1,__int64>,16,struct Eigen::MakePointer>)" (??R?$AdjustContrastv2@UGpuDevice@Eigen@@@functor@tensorflow@@QEAAXAEBUGpuDevice@Eigen@@V?$TensorMap@V?$Tensor@$$CBM$03$00_J@Eigen@@$0BA@UMakePointer@2@@4@V?$TensorMap@V?$TensorFixedSize@$$CBMU?$Sizes@$S@Eigen@@$00_J@Eigen@@$0BA@UMakePointer@2@@4@V?$TensorMap@V?$Tensor@M$03$00_J@Eigen@@$0BA@UMakePointer@2@@4@@Z)
1>tf_core_lib.lib(sqlite.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close
```

I've looked everywhere for similar posts, but couldn't find anything about those linker issues. The most related github issue I could find was [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7258).

What I am trying to achieve is the following: I want to call some inference methods on my Tensorflow model from inside Unity, i.e. C#. I wasn't able to use [TensorFlowSharp](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp) because Unity has some restrictions on the .NET version and somehow removing .NET 4.7 from my Windows was harder than expected. I know how to import a C++ DLL into Unity and use it, however the problem is that I can't build this DLL (i.e., in its simplest form, the program snippet above) at the moment. If you know of simpler solutions to this problem (i.e., not necessarily going through C++ but using Python bindings directly), I would be more than happy to hear about them.

Comment: How did you build tensorflow? what are your cmake command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I've built tensorflow from source on windows 10 and had similar linking errors. I had disabled compiler optimizations. After turning the optimizations on again, the linking errors were gone.